# How to retrieve the value of a variable in another page?

Tags: javascript

I have a btc.html/js page where I calculate the btc rate of variation every minute then I add it all up. I display all the data correctly on my btc.html page.

[image: image 1]

My problem is that I want to display the total --> `<td><span id="btcResult4Total"></span></td>` in the index.html page but it doesn't work. :S

The output displays `NaN`

[image: image 2]

I added `<script src="btc.js"></script>` in index.html page, but it doens't work. :S

I copied the project via Stackblitz for information -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-wtdkvy?file=btc.js

Thank you in advance for your help and your time.

**btc.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Crypto</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container mt-3">
    <h2>BITCOIN : <span id="formateDate"></span></h2>
    <hr>
    <table class="table table-bordered">

      <thead class="table-success">
        <tr class="text-center">
          <th>1 minute</th>
          <th>2 minutes</th>
          <th>3 minutes</th>
          <th>4 minutes</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr class="text-center">
          <td><span id="btcValue1"></span></td>
          <td><span id="btcValue2"></span></td>
          <td><span id="btcValue3"></span></td>
          <td><span id="btcValue4"></span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

      <thead class="table-success">
        <tr class="text-center">
          <th>1min-2min</th>
          <th>2min-3min</th>
          <th>3min-4min</th>
          <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr class="text-center">
          <td><span id="btcResult1"></span></td>
          <td><span id="btcResult2"></span></td>
          <td><span id="btcResult3"></span></td>
          <td><span id="btcResult4Total"></span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    
    </table>

    <hr>

  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="btc.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**btc.js**

```
console.clear();

let wsBtc = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade');

let btcStockPriceElement1 = document.getElementById('btcValue1');
let btcStockPriceElement2 = document.getElementById('btcValue2');
let btcStockPriceElement3 = document.getElementById('btcValue3');
let btcStockPriceElement4 = document.getElementById('btcValue4');

let btcLastPrice = null;
let btcStockObject = null;

wsBtc.onmessage = (event) => {
  btcStockObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
};
let btc1, btc2, btc3, btc4;
let btcVariation_1_2, btcVariation_2_3, btcVariation_3_4;
let btcVariationTotal_4;

let runTimers = setInterval(() => {
  let minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
  if (minutes === 29) {
    let val1 = parseFloat(btcStockObject.p).toFixed(1);
    let price = parseFloat(btcStockObject.p).toFixed(1);

    btcStockPriceElement1.innerText = price;
    btcStockPriceElement1.style.color =
      !btcLastPrice || btcLastPrice === price
        ? 'black'
        : price > btcLastPrice
        ? '#AAFF00'
        : 'red';

    btcLastPrice = price;
    btcStockObject = null;

    btc1 = val1;

    
  }

  if (minutes === 30) {
    let val2 = parseFloat(btcStockObject.p).toFixed(1);
    let price = parseFloat(btcStockObject.p).toFixed(1);

    btcStockPriceElement2.innerText = price;
    btcStockPriceElement2.style.color =
      !btcLastPrice || btcLastPrice === price
        ? 'black'
        : price > btcLastPrice
        ? '#AAFF00'
        : 'red';

    btcLastPrice = price;
    btcStockObject = null;

    btc2 = val2;

    btcVariation_1_2 = ( (parseFloat(btc2) - parseFloat(btc1)) / btc1 * 100);

    document.getElementById("btcResult1").innerHTML = btcVariation_1_2.toFixed(2);
    
  }

  if (minutes === 31) {
    let val3 = parseFloat(btcStockObject.p).toFixed(1);
    let price = parseFloat(btcStockObject.p).toFixed(1);

    btcStockPriceElement3.innerText = price;
    btcStockPriceElement3.style.color = !btcLastPrice || btcLastPrice === price ? 'black' : price > btcLastPrice ? '#AAFF00' : 'red';

    btcLastPrice = price;
    btcStockObject = null;

    btc3 = val3;

    btcVariation_2_3 = ( (parseFloat(btc3) - parseFloat(btc2)) / btc2 * 100);

    document.getElementById("btcResult2").innerHTML = btcVariation_2_3.toFixed(2);
  

  }

  if (minutes === 32) {
    let val4 = parseFloat(btcStockObject.p).toFixed(1);
    let price = parseFloat(btcStockObject.p).toFixed(1);

    btcStockPriceElement4.innerText = price;
    btcStockPriceElement4.style.color =
      !btcLastPrice || btcLastPrice === price
        ? 'black'
        : price > btcLastPrice
        ? '#AAFF00'
        : 'red';

    btcLastPrice = price;
    btcStockObject = null;

    btc4 = val4;

    btcVariation_3_4 = ( (parseFloat(btc4) - parseFloat(btc3)) / btc3 * 100);
    
    document.getElementById("btcResult3").innerHTML = btcVariation_3_4.toFixed(2);

  }

  btcVariationTotal_4 = (parseFloat(btcVariation_1_2) + parseFloat(btcVariation_2_3) + parseFloat(btcVariation_3_4));
  document.getElementById("btcResult4Total").innerHTML = btcVariationTotal_4.toFixed(2);

 

}, 60000);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Crypto</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h5 class="pt-3 pb-3">Date : <span id="formateDate"></span></h5>

    <table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th colspan="2" class="text-center" >Crypto</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td class="text-center w15"><a href="btc.html">BTC</a></td>
              <td class="text-center w15"><span id="btcResult4Total"></span></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="btc.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
let today = new Date();
let day = today.getDate();
let month = today.getMonth() +1;
let year = today.getFullYear();
let hour = today.getHours();
let minute = today.getMinutes();

let formateDate = day+'-'+month+'-'+year + '---' + hour+'h'+minute;

document.getElementById('formateDate').innerHTML = formateDate;
```

**style**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table,
td {
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

thead,
tfoot {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

.w15 {
    width: 15%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.html and btc.html are opening their own instances of `<script src="btc.js">`
these instances are independent of each other so when your code runs in btc.html it is not seen by index.html. To overcome this, after running the code in btc.html you save the results to sessionStorage then have index.html check your sessionStorage and display the results if they are available.

in btc.js, I'm assuming btcVariationTotal_4 is the final total you want displayed in index.html??? If so, then in btc.js after you get the total, save it to sessionStorage like this:

```js
sessionStorage.setItem("total", btcVariationTotal_4);
```

Then in index.html, REMOVE `<script src="btc.js">` and `<script src="script.js">` since they only seem to be needed in btc.html.  Then add this after your closing `</body>` tag to retrieve the total from sessionStorage like follows (note, this is not a real time update, you will need to implement a refresh or button to trigger the retrieval from sessionStorage each time:

```js
<script>
let totalToDisplay = sessionStorage.getItem("total");
if(totalToDisplay == null){
 // if there is nothing in sessionStorage, just display 0, or whatever default you want deisplayed
document.getElementById('btcResult4Total').innerHTML = 0;
}else{
// if theres an amount in there, display it.
document.getElementById('btcResult4Total').innerHTML = totalToDisplay;
}
</script>
```